# JQuery check which input textbox's border color is red before redirecting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question. I design a button and when user clicks this button, it triggers a function to check which input textbox is red using JQuery. If one box is found, stop on this page instead of redirecting, and inform user that there is invalid input. Here is a demo: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/fzcvsj1m/)

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" list="list" autocomplete="on" name="client" id="clientTxt" style="border-color: red; display: inline-block;">
<input type="text" list="list1" autocomplete="on" name="Installation" id="Installation" style="border-color: red; display: inline-block;">
<input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-submit">
```

JQuery Code:

```
$('#create-submit').click(function (event) {
    $('input[type = text]').each(function (event) {
        if ($(this).css('border-color') == 'red') {
            alert("Please check red input boxes and click create again.");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

However, in demo the JQuery function is not working as expected. Please help me with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Checking styles for logical reasons is bad practice. I'd seriously consider using a data attribute, or at least a CSS class.

Comment: Please give me an example. Thanks @isherwood

Comment: Also, use the form's submit event rather than click. What if the user hits enter?

Comment: @isherwood, thanks for your advice. I will use form's submit event

Comment: Because the border-color is rgb(255, 0, 0) (not "red").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
$("#create-submit").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var res = $("input[type=text]").toArray().some(function(el) {
    return $(el).css("border-color") === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
  });
  // `border-color` === `rgb(255, 0, 0)` , `border-color`:`"red"`
  if (res) {
    alert("Please check red input boxes and click create again.");
  } else {
    // do other stuff
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" list="list" autocomplete="on" name="client" id="clientTxt" style="border-color: red; display: inline-block;">
<input type="text" list="list1" autocomplete="on" name="Installation" id="Installation" style="border-color: red; display: inline-block;">
<input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-submit">
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fzcvsj1m/2/

Comment: You are welcome:) Does `js` return expected results ?

Comment: Hi @guest271314, would you please tell me what does 'toArray().some(...)' do?

Comment: @tonymiao See http://api.jquery.com/toArray/ _"Retrieve all the elements contained in the jQuery set, as an array."_ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some _"The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function."_ . If one of the `input` elements has `.css("border-color") === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"` return `true`

Comment: Great! I like your way.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

**CSS**

```
.error{
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" list="list" autocomplete="on" name="client" id="clientTxt" class="error">
<input type="text" list="list1" autocomplete="on" name="Installation" id="Installation" class="error">
<input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-submit">
```

**JS**

```
$('#create-submit').click(function (event) {
    $('input[type = text]').each(function (event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            alert("Please check red input boxes and click create again.");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here's an alternative with a data attribute. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fzcvsj1m/1/

Comment: Thanks for your quick update Alexey. The reason why I didn't use CSS is that I use $('#Installation').css('border-color', 'red'); to set a red installation textbox border color. So the style part in html input is auto-add using JQuery before validation check above. So I don't have CSS file.