# jQuery: check if element has specific style (not inline)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to check via jQuery or vanilla JS if an element has a specific style?

In my case I want to check if any input-fields on the page have a red border — applied via an external CSS-File. No inline-css and no `style`-attr is available, styling is completely external.

For my initial testing I got the following code from this StackOverflow-Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659187

```
$('.formValidation input[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var res = $('.formValidation input[type=text],.formValidation input[type=email],.formValidation input[type=url],.formValidation input[type=password]').toArray().some(function(el){
    return $(el).css('border-color') === 'rgb(255,0,0)'
  });
  if (res) {
    console.log('Still at least one field to go!');
  } else {
    console.log('You can submit!');
  }
});
```

… but .css seams to only test inlineStyles.

**Update**
I can't change HTML, the markup has to stay «as is». The red border is coming through css only. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z3t6k04s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 $('.formValidation input[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
        // Prevent Default Form Submit
         e.preventDefault();

        // Define Global if Invalid Fields Exist
        var hasInvalidInputs = false;

        // Run Through all to check Input Fields
        $('input').filter(function(index){

          // Check if Invalid Inputs already got detected. If not - check if this field is red
          if( !hasInvalidInputs )
            hasInvalidInputs = $(this).css('border-color') == 'rgb(161, 0, 0)';     // If field is red -> update global var to true
          });

        // Check if Invalid Fields are set to true
        if (hasInvalidInputs) {
          console.log('Still at least one field to go!');
        } else {
          console.log('You can submit!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

> [**Window.getComputedStyle()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
>
> *The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.*

Example:

```js
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

var style = window.getComputedStyle(inp, null);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue("border-color"))
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a one class which has a red color
like

```
.red-color{
 border-color:red;
}

$('.formValidation input[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var res = $('.formValidation input[type=text],.formValidation input[type=email],.formValidation input[type=url],.formValidation input[type=password]').toArray().some(function(el){
    return $(el).hasClass('red-color');
  });
  if (res) {
    console.log('Still at least one field to go!');
  } else {
    console.log('You can submit!');
  }
});
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: I can't add a class. HTML-Markup has to stay «as is». Red-Border is coming via CSS only. Have a look at the updated Question. but thx.

Comment: instead of check color check the validity of that , I update your jsfiddle please look that. https://jsfiddle.net/z3t6k04s/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
$('.formValidation input[type=submit]').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

var isValid;
$("input").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if (element.val() == "") {
       isValid = false;
     element.css('border-color','red');
   }else{
isValid = true;
     element.css('border-color','');
}
});
  if (isValid==false) {
    console.log('Still at least one field to go!');
  } else {
    console.log('You can submit!');
  }
});
```

Comment: You set the isValid variable in both branches of the first if-else to false. It will never become true.

Comment: That was bymistakely.thanks for correcting me @mizech